# REDIS : See everything that is under the "field"

Tags: hash, redis

It's quite complicated to explain.

What I want is to have a command that takes as a parameter the field and displays all keys and values ​​in this field.

I go around the REDIS documentation and I found HGETALL and HMGET, but these two commands do not meet my need.

HGETALL asks in parameter for the key and show all the fields with their value.
Example here : http://redis.io/commands/hgetall

HMGET takes in parameter the key and the field which are attached to it and show their values. Example here: http://redis.io/commands/hmget

There is also HKEYS but there either that does not give what I want.

If there is no very precise command, I shall like knowing how I could code so that that gives something close to what I wish to make and if it is possible.

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: Are you trying to fetch a particular field from many hashes?

Comment: Yes, I trying to fetch all of datas (keys and values) on a particular field. So from many hashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood it well, you have several Hash, each with its own key. Then you have in these hashes a field, for example the field "name". Now you want to ask something like "tell me in which keys I have stored the name attribute and what is the value"

If that's your case, there are some options to do that in redis, but it wouldn't be the best way of storing the information.

A possible way of doing this is using a common pattern for all the keys in which you will store the field name. For example "record:a", "record:b"... Then you could issue a KEYS command like KEYS record:  and you would get all the keys for your hashes. (note SCAN is more efficient)

Next you would need to issue several commands like hget key, name. You can use a MULTI so all the commands are executed at the same time.

With that process, you would get all the keys in the 1st step and all the values in the second. But I don't think this is optimal.

If I knew your use case, maybe I could help more

Comment: yes, that's why I wrote (note SCAN is more efficient). Of course only if you are using redis 2.8 or better.

Comment: SCAN is not more efficient, but it is incremental: it will not block the Redis instance for long. Anyway, I would rule out any solution based on scanning keys in general. If the OP requires fast access to the data from the field, an explicit index is required.

Comment: Yes, what I meant by "more efficient" was that no matter how big your keyspace, you always get a predictable time for everytime you run it, so you are not slowing down your instance. Also I agree it's not optimal, as I said on my answer. Once we know the use case, we can probably help the user better on how to have a secondary index.

Comment: I think that I'll answer within 8 hours. In the comment, i can't explain.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are understand but i'm not english and even if I translate on web-site (google-translate) I haven't all understand your answer. Sorry.

I have try with KEYS. I have the list of my fields used on my hashes. I have had an idea, It's do `bla=KEYS *`, do a `blas.each do |bla|` and in the each ... do, do @bla=hget(...,'bla'). Or something like this. But it's not possible, I haven't the key.

Infact I am trying to replace sqlite3 by Redis in Ruby on Rails scaffold is. it is in the controller where the index is displayed all values ​​in the hashes.

To be more clear :

```
 def index
    @counters = Counter.all
 end
```

I want replace this code by something like that :

```
def index
    @counters = REDIS.hget

  end
```